Determine the number of subsets with 3 elements of the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} with a property
the problems
Determine the number of subsets with 3 elements of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ that have the property that the arithmetic mean of its elements it is also an element of it.
my idea
My first thought after reading this problem was to use the property that says $\min(a_1,a_2,...a_n) \leq \frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n} \leq \max(a_1, a_2,..., a_n)$
I don't know what to do forward. An idea would be to take all the subsets that the set has and verify for each other if the property is verified.
Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

@julio_es_sui_glace Ok, so we have this type of combinations $(M_3+1, M_3+1,M_3+1), (M_3,M_3,M_3), (M_3+2, M_3+2,M_3+2), (M_3,M_3+1, M_3+2)$ and all the permutations but how is this going to help

"Propriety" means appropriate behaviour, what you meant to write was "property"

You should clarify if the arithmetic mean must be an element of the subset or an element of the ${1,\dots,10}$. The former is covered by Mathematician's answer, and the latter by Willy's.

@Kolakoski54 It must be an element of the subset

There can be two interpretations for your problem. Denoting $\text{AM}(S)$ the arithmetic mean of $S$, you want to count
(I) the number $n_1$ of size $3$ subsets $S$ of $\{1,\dots,10\}$ such that $\text{AM}(S)\in\{1,\dots,10\}$
or
(II) the number $n_2$ of size $3$ subsets $S$ of $\{1,\dots,10\}$ such that $\text{AM}(S)\in S$.

Case (I)
First notice that the fact the arithmetic mean is in $\{1,\dots,10\}$ is equivalent to the sum being a multiple of $3$. Let us reduce the problem "modulo 3" (meaning only considering the remainder after euclidian division by $3$):
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
n &1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\ \hline
n\text{ mod }3 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\\hline
\end{array}$$
Choosing 3 elements that add up to a multiple of $3$ is equivalent to choosing 3 elements whose remainders add up to a multiple of $3$. Here, the only possible sums for the rests are $0$, $3$ and $6$. For $0$ (resp. $6$), it is pretty easy: you only get $0$ (resp. $6$) if all the remainders are $0$ (resp. $2$), and that corresponds to the subset $\{3,6,9\}$ (resp. $\{2,5,8\}$). We now need to count the number of subsets whose remainders $\text{mod } 3$ add up to $3$, and we need to distinguish two cases based on the following observation:
$$3=\underbrace{1+1+1}_{\text{case 1}}=\underbrace{0+1+2}_{\text{case 2}}$$
case 1: (if all the remainders are $1$) those subsets are exactly the $3$-elements subsets of $\{1,4,7,10\}$, leading to $\binom{4}{3}=4$ choices.
case 2: (if all the remainders are distinct) to construct such subset, one needs to choose one element from $\{3,6,9\}$ ($3$ choices), one from $\{1,4,7,10\}$ ($4$ choices) and one from $\{2,5,8\}$ ($3$ choices), leading to
$$3\times 4\times 3=36\text{ choices}$$
Conclusion: $n_1=42$.
Remark: I could confirm my answer using the following python code:
import itertools

c=0
for l in list(itertools.combinations((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),3)):
    if sum(l)%3==0:
        c+=1
print(c)

which returns the value $c=42$.

Case (II)
Such a set is of the form $S=\{m-a,m,m+a\}$ with $a\geqslant 1$. For a fixed $m\in\{2,\dots, 9\}$, $a$ must be such that $m-a\geqslant 1$ and $m+a\leqslant 10$. The following table gives the set of possible values of $a$ for each $m$:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
m &2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9 \\ \hline
\text{possible values for }a & 1&1\to 2&1 \to 3&1\to 4&1\to 4&1\to 3&1\to 2&1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Summing on all the possible values, one gets $1+2+3+4+4+3+2+1=20$.
Conclusion: $n_2=20$.
Remark: I could confirm his answer using the following python code:
import itertools

c=0
for l in list(itertools.combinations((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),3)):
    if sum(l)/3 in l:
        c+=1
print(c)

which returns the value $c=20$.

It's not enough that the mean is in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}. It has to be in the specific subset with 3 elements.

That was the first interpretation I had for the OP's question. See @Kolakoski54 's comment.

I think the wording doesn't allow for that kind of interpretation, assuming Pam Munoz Ryan didn't make a mistake when writing the question. The relevant part reads: "the arithmetic mean of its elements it[sic] is also an element of it" [emphasis added]. I don't think it's possible that the two "it" (excluding the superfluous one) refer to different things.

Suppose that $a<b<c$.  Then $a+a+a<a+b+c<c+c+c$, and so $a<\frac{a+b+c}{3}<c$.  This means that if we have a 3 element set that contains its average, then the average must be the middlemost number.  Further, if $\frac{a+b+c}{3}=b$, then $\frac{a+c}{2}=b$.  Thus, if we say the smallest and largest element, then the middle element is fully determined.  Since all 3 elements must be integers, either $a$ and $c$ are both even, or $a$ and $c$ are both odd.
There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways to pick 2 even numbers from $1$ to $10$, and $\binom{5}{2}=10$ ways to pick 2 odd numbers from $1$ to $10$, for a total of 20 different choices for $a$ and $c$, and hence $20$ different 3-element sets satisfying the property.

There is a question of interpretation here: Does the final it refer to the set ${1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}$ or the three-element subset? In the second interpretation, your answer makes sense. For the first interpretation, see Willy's answer.

@N.F.Taussig Given the answer which the OP accepted, it would seem that he intended this interpretation.

First of all you have to note that
$$\frac{1+1+1}3=1\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$$
as well as
$$\frac{10+10+10}3=10\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$$
that is, there is no chopping off at either end.
However the quotient of the arithmetic mean generally has no reason to be integral only, that is, this is the true restriction of your additional property.
Thus let $a\leq b\leq c$. Then

$a=b=1\Rightarrow c=1,4,7,10$ (4 possibilities)
$a=1, b=2\Rightarrow c=3,6,9$ (3 possibilities)
$a=1, b=3\Rightarrow c=5,8$ (2 possibilities)
$a=1, b=4\Rightarrow c=4,7,10$ (3 possibilities)
$a=1, b=5\Rightarrow c=6,9$ (2 possibilities)
$a=1, b=6\Rightarrow c=8$ (1 possibility)
$a=1, b=7\Rightarrow c=10$ (1 possibility)
$a=1, b=8\Rightarrow c=9$ (1 possibility)
$a=1, b=9\Rightarrow$ 0 possibilities for $c$
$a=1, b=10\Rightarrow c=10$ (1 possibility)
$a=2, b=2\Rightarrow c=2,5,8$ (3 possibilities)
$a=2, b=3\Rightarrow c=4,7,10$ (3 possibilities)
$a=2, b=4\Rightarrow c=6,9$ (2 possibilities)
$a=2, b=5\Rightarrow c=5,8$ (2 possibilities)
$a=2, b=6\Rightarrow c=7,10$ (2 possibilities)
$a=2, b=7\Rightarrow c=9$ (1 possibility)
$a=2, b=8\Rightarrow c=8$ (1 possibility)
$a=2, b=9\Rightarrow c=10$ (1 possibility)
$a=2, b=10\Rightarrow$ 0 possibilities for $c$
$a=3, b=3\Rightarrow c=3,6,9$ (3 possibilities)
$a=3, b=4\Rightarrow c=5,8$ (2 possibilities)
$a=3, b=5\Rightarrow c=7,10$ (2 possibilities)
$a=3, b=6\Rightarrow c=6,9$ (2 possibilities)
$a=3, b=7\Rightarrow c=8$ (1 possibility)
$a=3, b=8\Rightarrow c=10$ (1 possibility)
$a=3, b=9\Rightarrow c=9$ (1 possibility)
$a=3, b=10\Rightarrow$ 0 possibilities for $c$
$a=4, b=4\Rightarrow c=4,7,10$ (3 possibilities)
$a=4, b=5\Rightarrow c=6,9$ (2 possibilities)
$a=4, b=6\Rightarrow c=8$ (1 possibility)
$a=4, b=7\Rightarrow c=7,10$ (2 possibilities)
$a=4, b=8\Rightarrow c=9$ (1 possibility)
$a=4, b=9\Rightarrow$ 0 possibilities for $c$
$a=4, b=10\Rightarrow c=10$ (1 possibility)
$a=5, b=5\Rightarrow c=5,8$ (2 possibilities)
$a=5, b=6\Rightarrow c=7,10$ (2 possibilities)
$a=5, b=7\Rightarrow c=9$ (1 possibility)
$a=5, b=8\Rightarrow c=8$ (1 possibility)
$a=5, b=9\Rightarrow c=10$ (1 possibility)
$a=5, b=10\Rightarrow$ 0 possibilities for $c$
$a=6, b=6\Rightarrow c=6,9$ (2 possibilities)
$a=6, b=7\Rightarrow c=8$ (1 possibility)
$a=6, b=8\Rightarrow c=10$ (1 possibility)
$a=6, b=9\Rightarrow c=9$ (1 possibility)
$a=6, b=10\Rightarrow$ 0 possibilities for $c$
$a=7, b=7\Rightarrow c=7,10$ (2 possibilities)
$a=7, b=8\Rightarrow c=9$ (1 possibility)
$a=7, b=9\Rightarrow$ 0 possibilities for $c$
$a=7, b=10\Rightarrow c=10$ (1 possibility)
$a=8, b=8\Rightarrow c=8$ (1 possibility)
$a=8, b=9\Rightarrow c=10$ (1 possibility)
$a=8, b=10\Rightarrow$ 0 possibilities for $c$
$a=9, b=9\Rightarrow c=9$ (1 possibility)
$a=9, b=10\Rightarrow$ 0 possibilities for $c$
$a=10, b=10\Rightarrow c=10$ (1 possibility)

Thus we get a total of 75 possibilities.
--- rk

The elements of a set are distinct.  You are counting multisets.

agreed, I indeed was considering "choosing with put back, without order". - Thus it might stay as an additional, closely related topic result...

Here's a calculation for general underlying set $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ (and three element subsets) using the idea in Mathematician's answer. We can write the indicator function of $a+c$ being even as $\large \frac{1+(-1)^{a+c}}{2}$ so the answer is
$$
\sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \sum_{c=a+2}^n \frac{1+(-1)^{a+c}}{2} \\
= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \left(  n-a-1 + \frac{(-1)^{2a+2}-(-1)^{a+n+1}}{1-(-1)}  \right )  \\
= \frac{1}{2}  \left( (n-1)^2 - \frac{n(n-1)}{2} + \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \frac{1-(-1)^{a+n+1}}{2}  \right )  \\
= \frac{1}{2}  \left( (n-1)^2 + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}  + \frac{1}{2} (n-1) - \frac{1}{2}  \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} (-1)^{a+n+1}  \right )  \\
= \frac{1}{2}  \left( (n-1)^2 + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}  + \frac{1}{2} (n-1) - \frac{1}{2}  \frac{(-1)^{n+2}-(-1)^{2n+1}}{2}  \right )  \\
= \frac{(n-1)^2}{4} - \frac{(-1)^{n}+1}{8}.
$$

Plugging in $n=10$ gives a non-integer value?

@Kolakoski54 Oops, had a sign error. Thanks for noticing.

Under the interpretation that the arithmetic mean must be an element of the subset
Notice that any $3$-element subset $\{a, b, c\}$ of $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ must have the form $\{m - d, m, m + d\}$, where $m$ is the arithmetic mean of the three integers in the subset and $d$ is an integer satisfying $1 \leq d \leq 4$. We consider cases:
$d = 1$: Then $2 \leq m \leq 9$.  There are $9 - 1 = 8$ such cases.
$d = 2$: Then $3 \leq m \leq 8$.  There are $8 - 2 = 6$ such cases.
$d = 3$: Then $4 \leq m \leq 7$.  There are $7 - 3 = 4$ such cases.
$d = 4$:  Then $5 \leq m \leq 6$.  There are $6 - 4 = 2$ such cases.
In total, there are $8 + 6 + 4 + 2 = 20$ three-element subsets of $S$ such that the arithmetic mean of the subset is an element of the subset.

I don't understand why the arithmetic mean must be in the subset: for example ${5,9,10}$ has arithmetic mean $8$.
